# Intellij idea, запуск внешней программы

Tags: intellij-idea

можно ли в intellij idea задать запуск внешней программы при компиляции и запуске самой программы в IDE?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чём вы видите проблему, какую задачу пытаетесь решить и т. д.

Answer (score 0):

При компиляции, средствами одной лишь IntelliJ IDEA, не знаю. Но при запуске из IntelliJ IDEA можно, если настроить в настройках запуска:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]